# How to find the smallest number on a right subtree

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I want to find the smallest number in a rignt subtree of a node, and this code below is what I thought that was the solution, but its not working properly. What is wrong with this code?

```
int small; // Where the smallest value is stored

int smallest(Node n)
{
    if(n.info < small && aux != 0) small = n.info;
    if(aux == 0)
    {
        aux = 1;
        small = n.dir.info;
        if(n!=NULL && n.dir!=NULL) return smallest(n.dir);
    }
    else{
        if(n.dir != NULL) return smallest(n.dir);
        if(n.esq != NULL) return smallest(n.esq); 
    }
    return small;
}
```

Comment: What is `small` and where is it declared?

Comment: I would said that is equal to find the smallest in a regular tree but instead of passing the root to that function, you pass the right subtree...

Answer (score 1):

I am using n.right for right subtree pointer and n.left for left subtree pointer

Just call the function smallest(n.right); smallest is a function that will find the smallest value in a binary tree

```
int smallest(Node n){
  if( n==NULL ) return INF;  // replace INF with the maximum value that int can hold in your system like 2147483647
  int left_small = smallest(n.left); // smallest value in left subtree
  int right_small = smallest(n.right); // smallest value in right subtree
  int ans = n.info;
  if( left_small < ans ) ans = left_small;
  if( right_small < ans ) ans = right_small;
  return ans;
}
```